# List View, date picker, Filter Android

Tags: android, android-listview, datepicker

I have created an adapter list view in android with two elements. The first one is the date of birth and the second is the name. I also add a date picker.

I want the user to pick a day on date picker and the app return the names who have their birth day in that specific day.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible?  Is there any example i can see?

Comment: how do you want to filter, with date picker, pls explain some more, i couldn't got you

Comment: I want the user to pick a day on date picker and the app return the names who have their birth day in that specific day. thanks

Comment: Kindly  update your question and be clear what you want, it is prone to down votes

Answer (score 0):

[image]

based on this image I have made, assuming this is want you want, great art work thanks to `PAINT`

your first view will be a `date picker` which you can make with the help of this link

[Date Picker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html)

your second view will be a `listview` which will be populated using the custom `adapter` you made which consist of two `textViews` (Date of Birth and Name),

depending on where you would be searching for the date selected in date picker you would have to update your `listview`

(`SQLite` databse or Remote server from where you want to check or a static list in your app)

And if this is not what you were looking for, Change the question so you might get a right answer :)

Comment: thanks you  answer. Actually i am looking for a code or an example for this step.

"depending on where you would be searching for the date selected in date picker you would have to update your listview"

Comment: Hi @Demetris, 
I am not sure if there would be specific tutorial for what you want to do, but I can tell you what you should learn so that you can create this by yourself,
>  learn Date Picker and place it value in EditText or TextView so user can see it.
>  Learn how to update ListView if it is already updated.
>  Learn SQLite or server connection (from where you want to search) 

if you still get the issue I will be free on weekend, will make something for you

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and your guidance.  It is better for me to try to do it alone. If I want any help I will let you know. Thanks a lot again.